# How do I link reference from Cloud Storage to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This might be a dumb question because I'm a beginner, but basically in the firebase console, I am trying to upload images to my firestore database but for the I can't seem to use the reference (I'm using the console website and most of the tutorials I see are from flutter itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are uploaded to Cloud Storage, not to Firestore.

Cloud Storage is for storing objects that you don't know (or don't care about) the structure of. Firestore you use to store documents that contain (nested) fields with JSON values.

You can upload files in the [Cloud Storage panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage) in the Firebase console.